# Fetch all files from MySQL database which having special character but I don't want to use "or" condition for all special character in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have lot of files in database with some special character files name. So I want to fetch all files which is having special character.

I have written the below query to fetch the files with special character.

For Example :

filename:

```
file!1.pdf 
file$2.pdf 
file!3.pdf
file*4.pdf
file&5.pdf
file$6.pdf
file£7.pdf
file8.pdf
file9.pdf
file10.pdf
```

The query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM file_managed
WHERE filename LIKE "%$%" OR filename LIKE "%!%" ;
```

or .........

It working fine but I have almost 25 special character to filter with. And I think this is not good query to achieve my requirement.

How can I write a query, so that I don't need to add "or" condition for all special character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
select fm.*
from file_managed fm
where filename regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9._]'
```

This will look for alphanumerics, underscore, and period.

If you have a specific exclusion list, use the same idea:

```
select fm.*
from file_managed fm
where filename regexp '[!@#$%^&*()]'
```

Just add the list between the `[` and `]`.  If those are invalid characters that you want to explicitly include, then use the regular expression escape character.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM file_managed WHERE filename LIKE '[!@#$%]'
```

Comment: Hi Michael , this query is not working for me. i am getting zero result .

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below query:

```
select 
*from file_managed
where filename regexp '[!@]'
```